# Set the header for web page so that IE doesn't cache the page but AKAMAI still does?

Tags: caching, http-headers, akamai

I'm setting the headers for a web page to CacheControlMaxAge 900 secs. This works well with Akamai and all the browsers ignore this setting except IE which caches the page for 9 minutes.

What I want is to have only Akamai cache the page for 9 minutes and no caching done by the browser (IE this is the one we have troubles with).

Web server: IIS 7

Comment: How does Akamai work? Does it fetch your pages the normal way? Does it have a specific user agent string?

Comment: Akamai will look at the last modified date and if it's within the max age it will go back to the origin server and collect new content. Otherwise it will just render the stale content.

Answer (score 1):

Akamai lets you separately set the Browser Cache Control Headers (how long before browser revisits an Akamai edge server for a file) and edge server Time To Live Rules (how long before the edge server revisits the origin for a file).

If what you want is for the browser to never cache and for the edge servers to refresh from your origin every 9 minutes, here's what you do:

1. Under Browser Cache Control Headers, choose *"Add cache busting headers to cacheable content and remove the default Akamai caching headers"*. That'll put no-cache and no-store in your page headers.
2. Under Time To Live Rules, set the server TTL to 9 minutes.